# Form data isn't submitted to the server

Tags: django, forms, django-views

The following is all I have for the client server

```
<div>
    <form action="/next/" role="form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

and from the server(django) I just want to process the form.

```
def next(request):
  request.body // nothing here except CSRF
  request.POST // nothing here except CSRF
```

It's embarrassing, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not embarrassing. you just forgot `name` attribute in form element that you want to catch in backend.

```
<textarea name="element_name" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
```

and in views.py

```
def next(request):
   if request.method == "POST": 
       textarea_value = request.POST.get('element_name') # viola!
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `name` attribute to the text area:

```
<textarea name="some_name" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a "name" attribute to the textarea ?